# Delete a specific file from cache every few minutes from a service worker?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a service worker fetching and caching files from my webserver. And it serves it from local cache if the requested resource is available. But I see the service worker's cache doesn't respect the cache headers of the resource and seems to keep it forever.

I need to purge my home page / from cache every 3 minutes. And another URL /trust/me.php every 3 hours.

I wrote a function like this to delete the home page from my cache every 3 mins:

```
setInterval(caches.open('mycache-v1').then(function(cache) 
{cache.delete('/').then
 ( function(response) 
  { 
  console.log('Cache deleted for home page.');
  }
 );
}), 180000);
```

But this doesn't work. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Your resource will be deleted from cached using above code. What does not working?

Comment: It doesn't delete it. I don't see log too in console. And it shows me the old page. Btw, this code is within my service worker and not on the website.

Comment: I tried this code and it worked. You should move this code from service worker to your website as this is not part of service worker at all.

Comment: Ok, great. Let me do that.

Answer (score 2):

Service worker cache does not automatically honor Cache-Control headers. Instead you need to create your own cache invalidation logic.
There are numerous ways to manage this and no one answer is correct for all assets in an app, nor every app.

You can set up a routine that periodically checks while the user is actively using your application to see if there are updates. I typically use a HEAD request to check for updates, but also use a cache manifest file from time to time. I wrote about the later in my book a few years ago.

You may also want to set a time to live TTL on an asset. For this I typically keep a hash table in IndexedDB to compare against.